# Undefined references, but symbols don't match. Function is compiled and exist in static library

Tags: c++, linux, centos7, ld, nm

Can anyone point my in the right direction? This is proprietary code so I can't upload the makefiles.

But here's the output of nm on `libA`:

```
libA.a:someOfile.o:                 U _Z12funcABCPcPA80_cii
libA.a:overhead.o:                 U _Z12funcABCPcPA80_cii
```

And here is nm of `libB`, where the function of interest rendering `undefined references` from two other functions:

```
libB.a:funcABC.o:0000000000000000 T _Z12funcABCPcPA64_ci
```

There was a similar project done that matches `_Z12FUNCABCPcPA64_ci`. Im working porting the code base to support a new platform.

This nm output of the similar project:

```
libB.a:funcABC.o:0000000000000000 T _Z12funcABCPcPA64_c


libA.a:overhead.o:                 U _Z12funcABCPcPA64_c
```

Clarification:
I only replaced the function name for the sake of posting on SO :)

Original function signature, on both projects:

```
#define LENGTH 64

bool funcABC( char* arg1, char arg2 [][LENGTH], int arg3)
```

Solution:

The library in question wasn't ported correctly. That is `libB` was an older version, that I didn't port. Thus it kept giving linking errors because of the comments below. `libB` should had the following declaration, and I should have been careful on reading the function definition.

```
bool funcABC(char*arg1, char arg2 [] [LENGTH_INHEADER], int arg3, int arg4)
```

In `funcABC.cpp`, the width of `arg2` was based on `LENGTH 64`. In `funcABC.h`, the width was intended to be `LENGTH_INHEADER 80`.

Comment: It's not the same. One has a 64 and one has 80

Answer (score 2):

I presume you replaced a proprietary name with `funcABC`. This breaks the mangling ABI. If the original name was 12 characters long, you should have replaced 12 with the new length.

- `_Z7funcABCPcPA80_cii` demangles to `funcABC(char*, char (*) [80], int, int)`
- `_Z7funcABCPcPA64_ci` demangles to `funcABC(char*, char (*) [64], int)`
- `_Z7funcABCPcPA64_c` demangles to `funcABC(char*, char (*) [64])`

These are completely different functions.

Comment: Btw, how were you able to demange the symbols? I'd like to add this to my debugging knowledge base.

Comment: @kroger9 There are tools like c++filt, llvm-cxxfilt, and demumble.